# Key mappings in vim cant find patterns

Tags: key-bindings

I'm new to vim and I'm trying to figure out the key mapping.
I've defined the following key map:

```
imap \i INSERT INTO <??> VALUES <??> ( <??> ); <??>
imap \j <Esc>/<??> <CR> ciw
map \j <Esc>/<??> <CR> ciw
```

when I hit `\j` vim is not able to find the `<??>` pattern after the semicolon in:

```
imap \i INSERT INTO <??> VALUES <??> ( <??> ); <??>
```

I get the following error:

```
E486: Pattern not found: <??>
```

help will be appreciated :).

Comment: Sorry newbie mistake.
There were trailing spaces at the end of `<??>`
I feel stupid now.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what does this mapping do? How does it work?

Comment: Glad you asked. These mappings are for MySQL statements. when I perform the command `\i` while in insert mode (imap - insert mode mapping) it autofills with  `INSERT INTO <??> VALUES <??> ( <??> ); <??>` and I've made the `<??>`  so as to work like a bookmark. When I perform `\j` it searches for the pattern `<??>` and jumps me to the position and deletes the tags(ciw - change in word) so I can type in the values I want.

Comment: interesting use-case. Nice question. Hope somebody might be able to help here. I have been using crude `vim abbreviations` to put the SQL query construct on editor. Not very stylish and useful though, just makes sure you dont mess us with query syntax